# Update a field if the value of a pattern is true

Tags: r, street-address

This is my first question so please excuse the mistakes.
I have a dataframe where the address is in one line and has many missing values and several errors.

Address

- Braemor Drive, Clontarf, Co.Dublin
- Meadow Avenue, Dundrum
- Philipsburgh Avenue, Marino
- Myrtle Square, The Coast

I would like to add a new field "District", if the value of the address contains certain values for example if it contains Marino, Fairview or Clontarf the District should be Dublin 3.

```
Dublin3 <- c("Marino", "Fairview", "Clontarf")
matches <- unique (grep(paste(Dublin3,collapse="|"), 
DubPPReg$Address, value=TRUE))
```

Using R, how can I update the value of District where the match is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# I've created example data frame with column Adress
df <- data.frame(Adress = c("Braemor Drive",
                            "Clontarf",
                                "Co.Dublin",
                                "Meadow Avenue",
                                "Dundrum",
                                "Philipsburgh Avenue", 
                                "Marino",
                                "Myrtle Square", "The Coast"))
# And vector Dublin
Dublin3 <- c("Marino", "Fairview", "Clontarf")

# Match names in column Adress and vector Dublin 3
df$District <- ifelse(df$Adress %in% Dublin3, "Dublin 3",FALSE)

    df
               Adress District
1       Braemor Drive    FALSE
2            Clontarf Dublin 3
3           Co.Dublin    FALSE
4       Meadow Avenue    FALSE
5             Dundrum    FALSE
6 Philipsburgh Avenue    FALSE
7              Marino Dublin 3
8       Myrtle Square    FALSE
9           The Coast    FALSE
```

Instead of `FALSE` you can choose something else (e.g. `NA`).

**Edited:** If your data are in vector

```
df <- c("Braemor Drive, Churchtown, Co.Dublin",
        "Meadow Avenue, Clontarf, Dublin 14",
        "Sallymount Avenue, Ranelagh", "Philipsburgh Avenue, Marino")
```

Which looks like this

```
df
[1] "Braemor Drive, Churchtown, Co.Dublin"
[2] "Meadow Avenue, Clontarf, Dublin 14"  
[3] "Sallymount Avenue, Ranelagh"         
[4] "Philipsburgh Avenue, Marino"
```

You can find your maches using `grepl` like this

```
match <- ifelse(grepl("Marino|Fairview|Clontarf", df, ignore.case = T), "Dublin 3",FALSE)
```

and output is

```
[1] "FALSE"    "Dublin 3" "FALSE"    "Dublin 3"
```

Which means that one or all of the matching names that you are looking for (i.e. Marino, Fairview or Clontarf) are in second and fourth row in `df`.

Comment: Thanks very much Miha. Your code example works perfectly when I tried it but I can't make it work on my example. If I have an exact match of the full address "Philipsburgh Avenue, Marino, Dublin 3", it works. But not for one word within the text.

Comment: Define / insert that one word in vector `Dublin3` and than run the code again.

Comment: When I try 
Dublin3 <- c("Avenue", "Fairview", "Clontarf") 
df$District <- ifelse(df$Adress %in% Dublin3, "Dublin 3",FALSE)

on the above df example, the results are false for all entries except for "Clontarf" which is an exact match.

Comment: In my data frame (df) there is no `Avenue` but there is `Meadow Avenue`. So if you would  also like to match`Avenue` to Dublin 3 you need to insert it into column `Adress`.

Comment: Hi Miha, I think we're talking at cross purposes here and I should have given a full code example. The dataframe consists of addresses in this format. 
df <- c("Braemor Drive, Churchtown, Co.Dublin", "Meadow Avenue, Clontarf, Dublin 14", "Sallymount Avenue, Ranelagh", "Philipsburgh Avenue, Marino")
And I need to find the ones that include the values from Dublin 3. 

Dublin3 <- c("Marino", "Fairview", "Clontarf")
It needs to pick up any addresses that contain that pattern, not just exact matches.

Comment: I edited my answer please take a look If this is what you need.